# Custom comment status possible?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, archives

I am a newbie to WordPress and I have some experience in PHP programming.

Recently, I have a lot of comments for my WordPress blog and I wanted to manage them in better order.

I wish to "archive" some comments in which I plan to release them later and get rid of them from the "pending" status.

There are currently 4 status for $comment_status:
moderated,
approved,
spam and
trash

I know that it is possible to add custom post types. Is it possible to add custom comment status? If possible, which file should I edit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer: no. There is not a built-in function to create a new comment status. The status of a comment (or a post/page/attachment/etc) contains wide-spread implications thoughout your Wordpress install, so you couldn't just add one somewhere quickly.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish by adding this new "status", but I think the closest thing you could use would be the add_comment_meta function which will append whatever info you want to that comment. You can then use that field to somehow differentiate from the statuses.

Take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status

Or, maybe here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta

That might help you get where you want to go.

Comment: It is just like the archive function in gmail. There are always comments that I don't want to throw to trash, do not want to display it, not spam but I just wanted to keep it.

Comment: Can I do so by modifying /wp-includes/comment.php ?

Comment: Sorry, my first link was incorrect. I've pasted the right one. It is an article about adding a post status, which is barely in development, but might help you.

And no, editing comment.php won't help you with that you're trying to do.