# comment_approved custom value

Tags: comments

I want to modify comments with an additional 'comment_approved' value. This value will be used elsewhere in a plugin that uses `wp_list_comments`.

Looking at the `wp_set_comment_status` function, I see this code (at about line 2371 in comment.php):

```
function wp_set_comment_status( $comment_id, $comment_status, $wp_error = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    switch ( $comment_status ) {
        case 'hold':
        case '0':
            $status = '0';
            break;
        case 'approve':
        case '1':
            $status = '1';
            add_action( 'wp_set_comment_status', 'wp_new_comment_notify_postauthor' );
            break;
        case 'spam':
            $status = 'spam';
            break;
        case 'trash':
            $status = 'trash';
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
```

I don't see a filter I can use to allow for another value (say "nodisplay" or "42") that will allow `wp_set_comment_status` to store my custom value.

Is there a way to store a custom value in the comment_approved field of the comments table?

The intent is to allow a plugin ajax call to set a comment to a status of '42' or 'nodisplay'. The plugin will also look for that value and remove that comment from the wp_list_comments process. (So a filter is also needed to intercept the output of wp_list_comments to remove that '42' comment from the displayed list.)

I note [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/103226/29416) has a similar intent, but it is from 2013, so perhaps there is a way now in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess that it isn't possible — at least not in this exact way — because of that `default: return false;` part of the code you reference: a custom value of the comment status will hit that and the function will stop immediately.

However, have you thought about using a comment metavalue to store the same data? You could:

1. **Set the value**: Set a custom meta on the offending comment, say `pluginname_comment_hide`, to `true` (I like removing negatives from values — e.g. `hide` is clearer than `nodisplay`).
2. **Don't display the comment**: This is trickier but I believe you could adjust the `meta_query` value in the `parse_comment_query` filter in [`WP_Comment_Query`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L274-L326) to remove the offending comments. (This might affect that back-end as well, so you'd want to do it conditionally.) You could also use the callbacks args on `wp_list_comments()` but you'd end up with comment counts that are off.

I don't know if that's too complex for an answer — let me know if more information would be helpful.